# NSMutableString appendString generates a SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablestring

This makes no sense to me.  Maybe someone here can explain why this happens.

I've got an NSMutableString that I alloc at the top of my iPhone app, then append to later in the process.  It results in a SIGABRT, which doesn't add up to me.  Here's the code:

Header File (simplified):

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    NSMutableString *locationErrorMessage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *locationErrorMessage;

@end
```

And the relevant parts of the Main:

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize locationErrorMessage;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    self.locationErrorMessage = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];  
}

- (void)anotherFunction {
    [self.locationErrorMessage appendString: @"Blah Blah Blah"];
}
```

This all seems simple enough.  What am I missing?

Comment: there must be some other relevant piece of code that you arent showing...post the crash log perhaps, it might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would call this a bug in how property setters are generated, but the answer is pretty simple:

You declared the property as `(nonatomic, copy)`.  This means that whenever the `locationErrorMessage` property is set, it's going to invoke `copy` on the new value and use that copy as the property value.

Unfortunately, invoking `copy` on an `NSMutableString` does not result in an `NSMutableString`, it results in an `NSString` (which cannot be mutated using something like `appendString:`).

So the simple fix would be to change the property declaration from `copy` to `retain`.

(I would say that the bug would be:  If you declare a property for a mutable object as `copy`, then the copy setter should actually use `mutableCopy` and not `copy`) => rdar://8416047

Answer (score 2):

Your property is copying the passed in string. A copy always is immutable, so you’re trying to send `appendString:` to an immutable `NSString`. Declare your property as `retain` and it will work or write a custom setter that copies the string using `mutableCopy`.

You also have a memory leak, you should use `[NSMutableString string]` instead of the `alloc-init` sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, you have a leak there,

```
self.locationErrorMessage = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

you're copying the value, but you never release the actual first allocated NSMutableString.